# How to build a generic stack ontop of a generic list? c++

Tags: c++

I currently have a generic stack class. However I want to change my stack class so that it uses my generic list class (both full codes are provided).  In other words, I want to build a generic stack using my generic list class.  I was hoping someone could help me.

My Stack class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 30;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            T data;
            Node *link;
        };

        Node *top;
        int num_items;

    public:
        // constructor
        // remember that an empty list has a "size" of -1 and its "position" is at -1
        Stack()
        {
            top = NULL;
            num_items = 0;
        }

        // copy constructor
        // clones the list l and sets the last element as the current
        Stack(const Stack& s)
        {
            *this = s;
        }

        // copy constructor
        // clones the list l and sets the last element as the current
        void operator=(const Stack& s)
        {
            Node *n = s.top;

            top = NULL;
            num_items = 0;

            // just loop through the list and copy each element
            while (n != NULL)
            {
                Push(n->data);
                n = n->link;
            }
        }

        //insert an item on top of the stack
        void Push(T data)
        {
            Node *n = new Node;
            n -> link =NULL;
            n -> data = data;

            if (top == NULL)
                top = n;

            else
            {
                n -> link = top;
                top = n;
            }
            num_items++;

        }
        //delete an item from the top of the stack (and return it)
        void Pop()
        {
            Node *n;

            if(IsEmpty ())
                return;
            else
            {
                n = top;
                top = top -> link;
                delete n;
            }
            num_items--;

        }

        //return(but do not delete) the item on top of the stack
        int Peek()
        {
            if(IsEmpty ())
                return -1;
            else
                return top -> data;

        }

        // return size of the stack
        int Size()
        {
            return num_items;

        }

        // returns if the list is empty
        bool IsEmpty()
        {
            if(top == NULL)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        // returns if the list is full
        bool IsFull()
        {
            if(num_items == MAX_SIZE)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        // returns the concatenation of two lists
        // s should not be modified
        // s should be concatenated to the end of *this
        // the returned list should not exceed MAX_SIZE elements
        // the last element of the new list is the current
        Stack operator+(const Stack& s) const
        {
            // copy the first list
            Stack t = *this;
            Node *n = s.top;

            // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
            while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
            {
                t.Push(n->data);
                n = n->link;
            }

            return t;
        }

        // returns if two lists are equal (by value)
        bool operator==(const Stack& s) const
        {
            // the lists are not equal if they're of different sizes
            if (num_items != s.num_items)
                return false;

            Node *p = top;
            Node *q = s.top;

            // iterate through each list
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                // if any pair of elements differ, the lists are not equal
                if (p->data != q->data)
                    return false;
                p = p->link;
                q = q->link;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // returns if two lists are not equal (by value)
        bool operator!=(const Stack& s) const
        {
            return !(*this == s);
        }

        // returns a string representation of the entire stack (e.g., 1 2 3 4 5)
        // the string "NULL" should be returned for an empty stack
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Stack &s)
        {
            // "NULL" if the stack is empty
            if (s.top == NULL)
                out << "NULL";
            else
            {
                Node *n = s.top;

                // otherwise iterate through the list and display each element separated by a space
                while (n != NULL)
                {
                    out << n->data << " ";
                    n = n->link;
                }
            }

            return out;
        }
};
```

And my GenericList class is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_SIZE = 30;

template <class T>
class List
{
    private:
        struct Node
        {
            T data;
            Node *link;
        };

        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        Node *curr;
        int num_items;

    public:
        // constructor
        // remember that an empty list has a "size" of -1 and its "position" is at -1
        List()
        {
            head = tail = curr = NULL;
            num_items = 0;
        }

        // copy constructor
        // clones the list l and sets the last element as the current
        List(const List& l)
        {
            *this = l;
        }

        // copy constructor
        // clones the list l and sets the last element as the current
        void operator=(const List& l)
        {
            Node *n = l.head;

            head = tail = curr = NULL;
            num_items = 0;

            // just loop through the list and copy each element
            while (n != NULL)
            {
                InsertAfter(n->data);
                n = n->link;
            }
        }

        // navigates to the beginning of the list
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        void First()
        {
            curr = head;
        }

        // navigates to the end of the list
        // the end of the list does not necessarily correspond to its maximum size; it's just at the last existing element
        void Last()
        {
            curr = tail;
        }

        // navigates to the specified element (0-index)
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        // this should not be possible for invalid positions
        void SetPos(T pos)
        {
            if (!IsEmpty() && pos >=0 && pos < num_items)
            {
                curr = head;

                // move curr to the specified position
                for (int i=0; i<pos; i++)
                    curr = curr->link;
            }
        }

        // navigates to the previous element
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        // there should be no wrap-around
        void Prev()
        {
            if (!IsEmpty() && curr != head)
            {
                Node *n = head;

                // move n to the previous element
                while (n->link != curr)
                    n = n->link;

                curr = n;
            }
        }

        // navigates to the next element
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        // there should be no wrap-around
        void Next()
        {
            if (!IsEmpty() && curr != tail)
                curr = curr->link;
        }

        // returns the location of the current element (or -1)
        int GetPos()
        {
            if (IsEmpty())
                return -1;

            Node *n = head;
            int i = 0;

            // traverse the list to get the current position
            while (n != curr)
            {
                n = n->link;
                i++;
            }

            return i;
        }

        // returns the value of the current element (or -1)
        int GetValue()
        {
            return ((!IsEmpty()) ? curr->data : -1);
        }

        // returns the size of the list
        // size does not imply capacity
        int GetSize()
        {
            return num_items;
        }

        // inserts an item before the current element
        // the new element becomes the current
        // this should not be possible for a full list
        void InsertBefore(T data)
        {
            if (!IsFull())
            {
                // if the list is empty, just insert after
                if (IsEmpty())
                    InsertAfter(data);
                else
                {
                    // if we're at the beginning, just create a new head that points to the current one
                    if (curr == head)
                    {
                        head = new Node;
                        head->data = data;
                        head->link = curr;
                        curr = head;
                        num_items++;
                    }
                    // otherwise, navigate to the previous node and insert after
                    else
                    {
                        Prev();
                        InsertAfter(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // inserts an item after the current element
        // the new element becomes the current
        // this should not be possible for a full list
        void InsertAfter(T data)
        {
            if (!IsFull())
            {
                Node *n = new Node;

                n->data = data;
                n->link = NULL;

                // if the list is empty, everything points to the single node
                if (IsEmpty())
                    head = tail = curr = n;
                else
                {
                    // if we're at the end, just tack the new node on
                    if (curr == tail)
                    {
                        curr->link = n;
                        curr = tail = n;
                    }
                    // otherwise, change the links to insert the node
                    else
                    {
                        n->link = curr->link;
                        curr = curr->link = n;
                    }
                }

                num_items++;
            }
        }

        // removes the current element (collapsing the list)
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        void Remove()
        {
            if (!IsEmpty())
            {
                // if we're at the beginning, reset the head
                if (curr == head)
                {
                    head = curr = curr->link;

                    if (head == NULL)
                        tail = NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    Prev();
                    // and rearrange the pointer to remove this node
                    curr->link = curr->link->link;
                    // we handle removing the tail vs. other internal nodes a bit differently
                    if (curr->link == NULL)
                        tail = curr;
                    Next();
                }
                num_items--;
            }
        }

        // replaces the value of the current element with the specified value
        // this should not be possible for an empty list
        void Replace(T data)
        {
            if (!IsEmpty())
                curr->data = data;
        }

        // returns if the list is empty
        bool IsEmpty()
        {
            return (head == NULL);
        }

        // returns if the list is full
        bool IsFull()
        {
            return (num_items == MAX_SIZE);
        }

        // returns the concatenation of two lists
        // l should not be modified
        // l should be concatenated to the end of *this
        // the returned list should not exceed MAX_SIZE elements
        // the last element of the new list is the current
        List operator+(const List& l) const
        {
            // copy the first list
            List t = *this;
            Node *n = l.head;

            // iterate through the second list and copy each element to the new list
            while (n != NULL && !t.IsFull())
            {
                t.InsertAfter(n->data);
                n = n->link;
            }

            return t;
        }

        // returns if two lists are equal (by value)
        bool operator==(const List& l) const
        {
            // the lists are not equal if they're of different sizes
            if (num_items != l.num_items)
                return false;

            Node *p = head;
            Node *q = l.head;

            // iterate through each list
            while (p != NULL)
            {
                // if any pair of elements differ, the lists are not equal
                if (p->data != q->data)
                    return false;
                p = p->link;
                q = q->link;
            }

            return true;
        }

        // returns if two lists are not equal (by value)
        bool operator!=(const List& l) const
        {
            return !(*this == l);
        }

        // returns a string representation of the entire list (e.g., 1 2 3 4 5)
        // the string "NULL" should be returned for an empty list
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const List &l)
        {
            // "NULL" if the list is empty
            if (l.head == NULL)
                out << "NULL";
            else
            {
                Node *n = l.head;

                // otherwise iterate through the list and display each element separated by a space
                while (n != NULL)
                {
                    out << n->data << " ";
                    n = n->link;
                }
            }

            return out;
        }
};
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work as you'd like here? I'm not exactly thrilled by the idea of reading your (longish) code, reverse engineer it to find out what it is supposed to do, and then debug it...

Comment: They both work. What I want to do is include the Generic list in my stack class. I know i have #include "Genericlist.cc" I'm just not sure how I would go about coding my stack class using the generic list class. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can just work with the end of the list.

So for the pop functionality you would get the last item in the list, remove it from the list, and return it to the caller.

For push you could do the reverse action ie add the item to the end of the list.